# Vite built Vue3 causing CSP object-src error when webpage is refreshed at browser (MS Edge)

Tags: vuejs3, vite, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

Browser refresh (MS Edge) is returning a CSP error in the console in production mode.

> The Content-Security-Policy directive 'plugin-types' has been removed from the specification. If you want to block plugins, consider specifying "object-src 'none'" instead.

Verified in production's IIS Azure webserver and my staging NGINX server (Debian 11/WSL). When project is run in Vite's "dev" mode (localhost), I am not seeing any CSP errors. Any suggestions?  I am stumped as there are no assets being linked to outside the production domain.

Production location: [defenseammunitioncenter.army.mil](https://defenseammunitioncenter.army.mil)

Comment: The error is just letting you know that particular CSP directive has been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/plugin-types).  You will need to configure your web server to not include that directive in the response header when serving the site, which you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/asQtyCq.png) on the network tab

Comment: @yoduh, thank you for the edit. Sounds much better than what I began with.

Comment: I agree what yoduh said, and the documentation he provided clearly shows that this header is no longer compatible in most modern browser versions, so I think you might want to consider redesigning this section.

Comment: @yoduh  Thank you for the direction.  I do not control the web server itself.  Responsibility of my client. I am in conversations with them this week.

Comment: @yoduh would this CSP stop the rendering of subpages (routes)? I am finding that as long as I use the vite/vue script where vite is the 'webserver', browser refreshes work like they are supposed to. But when I use something like VSCode's Live Server and run the rendered base index.html, I am finding that browser refreshes always get a http404 response for all subpages (localhost/classroom/ammo04).
Git Repo: https://github.com/anthony-jackman/vulcan.git
Live site: https://defenseammunitioncenter.army.mil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inserted a meta tag in the head section of the index.html.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none';">
```